# How can i edit recently viewed products widget layout?

Tags: magento2

I want to edit recently viewed products widget layout and override on my custom theme, but i can't reach to layout template under /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Ui\Block\Wrapper
 */
?>

<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderApp([
    'widget_columns' => [
        'displayMode' => 'grid'
    ],
    'image' => [
        'imageCode' => 'recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget'
    ]
]);
```

I edited before new products widget layout.
How can i do with same way?

Which file need i to copy under my template folder?

Answer (score 2):

the file you're looking for is probably this one:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/list/listing.html

But, pay attention **it's a UI component** so it may be used (as the file name suggest) in many other places